# Change AVPlayer source in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have an AVPlayer that plays a video in the background of my SwiftUI app which works fine.

But I need to allow the users to change the video on a button tap/click.

This is my code for playing video:

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var bgVideoURL = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"


struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return PlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
    }
}

class PlayerUIView: UIView {

    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let url = URL(string: bgVideoURL)!
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        
        player.play()

        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                               name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: player.currentItem)

        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    }
    
    

    @objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
        if let playerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
            playerItem.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

and this is how I play the video:

```
var body: some View {
    PlayerView()
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

I need to change the video on button click/tap so I tried this:

```
 .onTapGesture {

   player.pause()
   player.seek(to: .zero)

   bgVideoURL = "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"

   player.play()
                                        
   }
```

The above code will restart the `player` but it doesn't change the video/source of the player!

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, create a proper PlayerUIView class (Remove global variables, etc.)

PlayerUIView

```
class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    
    // MARK: Class Property
    
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    
    // MARK: Init
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    init(player: AVPlayer) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        self.playerSetup(player: player)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    // MARK: Life-Cycle
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
    // MARK: Class Methods
    
    private func playerSetup(player: AVPlayer) {
        playerLayer.player = player
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        
        self.setObserver()
    }
    
    func setObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                               name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: playerLayer.player?.currentItem)
    }
    
    @objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
        if let playerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
            playerItem.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
            self.playerLayer.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, use `@Binding` to bind your player in PlayerView

PlayerView

```
struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var player: AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PlayerUIView {
        return PlayerUIView(player: player)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PlayerUIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
        uiView.playerLayer.player = player
        
        //Add player observer.
        uiView.setObserver()
    }
}
```

in last, inside the content view make AVPlayer object, change your new URL with AVPlayer.

```
struct PlayerContentView: View {
    
    @State private var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4")!)
    
    var body: some View {
        PlayerView(player: $player)
            .onTapGesture {
                player.pause()
                player.seek(to: .zero)
                
                player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "temp_video", withExtension: "mp4")!) // or AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4")!)
                player.play()
                
            }
            .onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this need to be a local URL: `AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4", withExtension: "mp4")!)`

Comment: No. you can direct use ```AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4")!)``` I used for testing purpose and used local video so.

Comment: There's one issue with this which I can't figure out how to resolve. when a new video loaded, it doesn't loop. basically the Notification becomes useless and the video only plays once.

Comment: Do you know why the video stops looping if the source changes?

Comment: Not checked yet, will check

Comment: Try to remove code from NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

Comment: No. Remove this NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

Comment: Sorry, Ignore my last messages. its been a long day! OK, so I removed `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` but the video doesn't play at all!

Comment: Okay, so now I made the video playing again but when I change the video source, it doesn't loop. it only plays once. I have removed `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)` as well.

Comment: @roozfar check my updated ans. for loop video