# SwiftUI - How do I Press button -> Autoplay video with no controls -> Do rest of button actions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a video automatically play without any control buttons when a button is pressed and then after the video is done playing do the rest of the button actions.

I can get the video to play if I put it above the ZStack, but when I try to make it play after hitting a button inside the ZStack, then I get an error that says "Result of 'VideoPlayer' initializer is unused" on the line where VideoPlayer is.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    
//variable set

    ZStack {
          //Background
          Image(Background)
          VStack {
        
                //Various HStacks, all of which work fine
        
                Button(action: {
                      if number >= 9 {
                            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sunrise", withExtension: "mp4")!))
                            self.number -= 1
                      } else {
                            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sunset", withExtension: "mp4")!))
                      }
          }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change AVPlayer source in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045123/change-avplayer-source-in-swiftui)

Comment: @RajaKishan That does not appear to be what I'm looking for. It doesn't reference a video playing once upon clicking a button, without any controls, and then ending the video, and then doing the rest of the code (or doing the rest of the code in the background and displaying the result after the video). At least not that I could understand after reading that one.

Comment: Take look and check you will get ans from this. This ans is your reference. This is similar one.

Comment: Perhaps I should note that I'm a beginner. That link didn't have a ZStack at all and my button is in a ZStack. The video line of code only gives the error once it's in the ZStack. It might also have been helpful to note mine is in "struct ContentView: View {" and that link is in "struct PlayerView: View {"? I'll add that to my post for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `VideoPlayer` and loading different content for it, you need to put the `VideoPlayer` inside the view hierarchy. Right now, you have it inside the `Button`'s action, which means that even if you didn't have a compiler error, it would show up in your view.

Here's some code that loads different `AVPlayer`s based on the state of `number` and autoplays the video:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var number = 6
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4")!)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
            Button(action: {
                number += 1
                if number >= 9 {
                    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4")!)
                } else {
                    player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4")!)
                }
                player.play()
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding hiding the controls, you can't actually do that with `VideoPlayer`, but you can wrap `AVPlayerViewController` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928091/560942

Comment: I appreciate this! This cleared up the error I was getting for the VideoPlayer. For some reason though, the "@State var player" line is causing the app to crash. It says "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". What does this mean? It didn't show any error at all until I ran it and then it crashed with that error.

Comment: You're using `!` to force unwrap optional values -- if one of your files doesn't actually exist in your bundle, for example, it would cause that crash.

Comment: So, for example, if it didn't find "Sunrise.mp4" for example, then it would return that error? Because I've confirmed that "Sunrise.mp4" exists, it's loaded in the project so when I click it I can click play and it does play the video, and it is marked as belonging to the app target membership.

Comment: What about the other video? Somewhere, you're force unwrapping something that doesn't exist... This does not happen, for example, in my sample code.

Comment: Okay, now it's working, but now it is keeping a black box for the video player permanently on the screen. I only want the video to play if that button is pushed and for it to take up the whole screen, then when it's done playing go away unless the button is pushed again. Is there a way to make the video not be on the screen unless the button is pushed and disappear after 1 play?

Comment: Sure -- you can surround the `VideoPlayer` with an `if { }` block and only display it if a given condition is true. Maybe you set a `showPlayer` `@State` variable to true when the button is pressed, for example. Disappearing is a little more complicated. You can do some searching for finding out when an AVPlayer is done playing. By the way, please feel free to click the green checkmark to accept this answer if you feel that I've answered the original question.

Comment: Okay that worked. I also used .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) to make the video player fill the screen. In the preview, the video takes up the whole screen. When I build and test it in the simulator though, the video is scrunched up to the top, the app shows up at the bottom, and the video does not play. Is this because the if/else is doing more than just telling it to play the video? It also says, "<CATransformLayer: 0x600000c8c0c0> - changing property allowsGroupBlending in transform-only layer, will have no effect" which I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Nope, that can't be it, I changed it to only play the video and nothing else and it did the same thing. In preview, the video fills the screen. In Simulator, the video is pressed so far up you can only see the play/pause and scrub bar, and the rest of the interface takes up the bottom 95% of the screen, and the video doesn't play, it just loops like it's trying to load.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not an answer, I also don't want any likes for it .
You don't need to reinitialise the player every time, you want to set new url.
So here is some refactoring proposition:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var number = 6
@State private var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4")!)

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VideoPlayer(player: player)
        Button(action: {
            number += 1
            if number >= 9 {
                player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4")!))
            } else {
                player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4")!))
            }
            player.play()
        }) {
            Text("Button")
        }
    }
}
```

}